# I want my code to reiterate a process not, multiply C#

Tags: c#, .net

```
int currentpop = initialtownpop;
int finalpop = Convert.ToInt32(currentpop * growthfac) * yearnum;
```

I want the code to multiply the current population (currentpop) by the growth factor (growthfac) then repeat that process by the number of years which the user wants this process to continue.

For example this is what I want the program to do, population 333 * 1.3 = 433 * 1.3 = 563 (if yearnum = 2) as opposed to what it is doing now 333 * 1.3 * 2 = 866

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation

Comment: you should multiply `growthfac^yearnum` (to the power of yearnum).

Comment: @wannadream ^ - this function doesnt work in c#

Comment: For "power", use `Math.Pow`, because the `^` operator is something else entirely

Comment: I was giving you the math formula. :) In C#, use this, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=net-8.0